# JBoss 7.1 support status?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, redhat

We are using JBoss 7.1.1 and we basically dont pay anything to the Red Hat.

My first question is, since we are not paying for any support, this would be considers as JBoss community edition?

My next question is whats the current status of the JBoss support, is the community edition still considered as supported and where can I find this info?
I' m reading this [notes](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes), but I cant conclude anything from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JBoss 7.1.1 AS isn't supported by RedHat (AS products have now been renamed to Wildfly, which is basically the free version of JBoss). Yes you could say that it is the "community edition" of JBoss.
2. EAP products such as JBoss 7 EAP are supported, but they are commerical and you have to pay a subscription fee for their usage and support. Redhat typically backports bugfixes, etc. from its commercial versions to AS products, but this isn't guranteed and there is no fixed support cycle or maintenance phases in the case of the latter.

Comment: regarding 2) there are scripts available on github to build EAP (or something similar) from scratch, thus basically getting the EAP functionality without the subscription. Not promoting this, just saying it is available if for some reason, a migration directly to WFLY is not a possibility: https://github.com/hasalex/eap-build

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for community bits. The notes that you referred to is applicable for only enterprise (EAP) bits.

JBoss AS project has been migrated to the JBoss [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) community. The latest community release is WildFly 10 which is based on the JEE7 spec. JBoss AS 7 was a JEE6 implementation.